# what is the Xero openid configuration url

Tags: javascript, node.js, xero-api

do you know what is the open id configuration for xero. I need to implement the xero PKCE flow with "oidc-client-ts"

as a exsample google open id configuration url is
https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

so do Xero have a url like this to get open id configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does have it, the OpenID Config URL is:

https://identity.xero.com/.well-known/openid-configuration